# How can I select all possible JSON Data in arrow syntax/JSON Extract in SQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I need to be able to access all the available JSON data, the problem is that a lot of it is nested.

I currently have this query.

```
SELECT * FROM `system_log` WHERE entry->"$[0]" LIKE "%search_term%";
```

I need instead of `entry->"$[0]"`, something like `entry->"$*"`

I think the arrow syntax is short for JSON_EXTRACT which I think would mean that a solution for extract would work for the arrow syntax.

```
{
    " Name": {
        "after": "Shop",
        "before": "Supermarket"
    }
}
```

This is an example of my JSON data and as you can see there are multiple levels to it meaning that `entry->"$[0]"` won't catch it.

version 8.0.19 of SQL

What I've tried so far is `entry->"$[0]"` and then prepending [0] after, but this solution does not seem very dynamic as the JSON data could get deeper and deeper.

Comment: Can you for example explain more by adding an input and the output wanted

Comment: It seems that you need in JSON_SEARCH()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON_SEARCH() won't work for the search you describe, because JSON_SEARCH() only searches for full string matches, not wildcards.

If you truly cannot predict the structure of your JSON, and you just want to find if the pattern `'%search_term%'` appears anywhere, then just treat the whole JSON document as a string, and use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT * FROM `system_log` WHERE entry LIKE "%search_term%";
```

If you have more specific search requirements, then you'll have to come up with a way to predict the path to the value you're searching for in your JSON document. That's something I cannot help you with, because I don't know your usage of JSON.